# CardViewActivity cannot be resolved to a typе

Tags: android, eclipse

Пытаюсь в eclipse загрузить пример приложения.![введите сюда описание изображения][1]
Видимо, не может найти необходимые библиотеки. Я еще новичок и не знаю где их найти и как подключить.

```
 
    /*
    * Copyright 2014 The Android Open Source Project
    *
    * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
    * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    * You may obtain a copy of the License at
    *
    *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    *
    * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    * limitations under the License.
    */
    package com.example.android.cardview;
```

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

/**
 * Unit tests for CardView samples.
 */
public class SampleTests extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<CardViewActivity> {

    private CardViewActivity mActivity;
    private CardViewFragment mFragment;

    public SampleTests() {
        super(CardViewActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        mActivity = getActivity();
        mFragment = (CardViewFragment) mActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id
                .container);
    }

    public void testPreconditions() {
        assertNotNull(String.format("%s is null", CardViewActivity.class.getSimpleName()),
                mActivity);
        assertNotNull(String.format("%s is null", CardViewFragment.class.getSimpleName()),
                mFragment);
        assertNotNull("SeekBar for Radius is null", mFragment.mRadiusSeekBar);
        assertNotNull("SeekBar for Elevation is null", mFragment.mElevationSeekBar);
    }

    public void testRadiusSeekbarChangesRadiusOfCardView() {
        getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                float radius = 50.0f;
                mFragment.mRadiusSeekBar.setProgress((int) radius);
                assertEquals(radius, mFragment.mCardView.getRadius());
            }
        });
    }

    public void testElevationSeekbarChangesElevationOfCardView() {
        getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                float elevation = 40.0f;
                mFragment.mElevationSeekBar.setProgress((int) elevation);
                assertEquals(elevation, mFragment.mCardView.getElevation());
            }
        });
    }
}</pre> </code>!>

Comment: Во-первых, приводите код и сообщения об ошибках в текстовом виде, а не в виде скриншота. Во-вторых, вы уверены, что правильно скопировали пример? Компилятор жалуется на отсутствие классов `CardViewActivity` и `CardViewFragment`. В вашем проекте я их не вижу.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо импортировать нужные классы.

Например так:

1) Установите курсор на строчку с ошибкой.

2) Нажмите Ctrl+1

3) В появившемся меню выберите класс, который надо импортировать.

Comment: Видимо, проблема заключается не в этом. Потому, как IDE предлагает создать класс самому. Могу предположить, что Eclipse не находит нужных библиотек. Но как это исправить не знаю, ибо еще зеленый в этом.

Comment: Значит да, надо либу добавить. Откуда пример?

Comment: (Eclipse) File -> New Project -> Other -> Android -> Android Samlpe Project -> Android 5.1.1 -> "ui > views > CardView > Application > tests"

Comment: Вы какой-то не тот проект посмотреть хотите... Вам, думаю, нужен Support7Demos, к коему надо подключить в виде библиотек все проекты из папки **путь к Eclipse\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\**